# How random forest work? (Manual calculation)

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I just learned about the concept of random forest (how the algorithm works) and I am confused on two things:

1. If I use majority vote to classify something and I have 52 trees. I get result like this:

   - Label 1 : 12
   - Label 2 : 20
   - Label 3 : 20

   So, where will my data be classified? Label 2 or label 3?
2. I created a random forest considering the information gain of each feature in every tree (I do it manually, not with program). One of my tree like this:
   [image]
   Age have three attributes: middle_age, youth, and senior, but when I created node 1.1.2, data for youth age were absent,  like this:
   [image]
   My question is if I want to classify data that has features student = yes, credit = excellent, and age = youth, what label will I get?

Can anyone explain it? I'm still a beginner in machine learning

Comment: Are you sure it’s “middle age” vs “senior” split, rather then vs “other”? Where did you get the tree? Decision trees make binary splits, so it does not seem valid.

Comment: I use ID3 algorithm, I follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UdTKxGQvYdc)